# Maximising Java application (vanilla data processing) performance

Tags: java, performance, scala, optimization, jvm

Not the first time that I've come across this problem.

I optimise my Scala / Java code by looking at Flight Recorder recordings in Java Mission Control. Look at hottest methods, then memory allocations, and eventually the application runs 50x faster, or 3x faster.

Once I get to this point, the CPU usage is 60-90% and memory usage is for instance 2GB out of the maximum 4GB heap. Yet I think I could push out a lot more speed.

Characteristics:

- Single thread processing, reading a single file from the filesystem.
- Sequential reading where the filesystem read speed is 1GB/s, but the processing is as slow as 5MB/s (branching, state machines, etc).
- Minimised the garbage collections where I could.
- No fancy libraries, just pure JVM code.

Code looks roughly like this (in pseudocode):

```
for line in file // using an iterator which would call into a file
  result = process_line(line)
  state = state.process(result)
  if state.emits:
    println(state.result)
```

In one application I have the following hottest methods:

```
scala.collection.immutable.HashMap$HashTrieMap.getO(Object, Int, Int)  6.75%
java.io.BufferedInputStream.read() 4.97%
```

In another (this is off the top of my head):

```
(some sort of garbage collection process) 9%
...       7%
```

Is it still worth optimising these? I have tried, and gained very little performance improvement for much more complex code.

Where should I look next?

Should I consider doing `process_line()` on one thread and then iterate the state on another thread to minimise the context switching? Perhaps that is what slows things down?

What is the right way about this? I don't want to parallelise the problem itself just yet.

Comment: I would focus on where you are spending the most time using CPU and see if you can optimise it or pass the work to another thread. I.e. you are heading in the right direction, you need to keep optimising.

Comment: I updated the question to include a bit more detail. There is no 'hottest' method, there are a bunch from different packages using roughly similar amount of CPU.

Comment: I would be suspicious of a sorted collection like you have and see if you can write the code without it.  BufferedInputStream.read() shouldn't be so expensive as it should be reading blocking of bytes at a time ideally, but it depends on why you are doing this. I would look at how many method are "noise" esp collection operations, and not the core logic of what your application does.

Comment: If you're concerned about the cost of context switches you should measure them. and other OS-level statistics along with them while you're at it. And since you're doing println, have you tried redirecting to `/dev/null`?

Comment: @the8472 Not printing any output yielded an 8% performance boost. How would you measure such context switches on Mac / Linux?

Comment: gnu time (not the bash built-in), perf (with perf-map-agent for java) and strace are useful to probe from the OS side. and yes, you should move IO onto a separate thread and have them talk each other through queues, this will decouple throughput from IO latency.

Answer (score 0):

I would parallelize the reader.

If the data is on disk, you could create one thread that reads data from disk in chunks and another that processes it. This is, by the way, how Java Mission Control 4 reads recording files. Or you could do like Java Mission Control 5, that uses a RandomAccessFile which it reads from multiple threads and then the result is stitched together.